# Is there a way in maven to assure that a property is set

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml

I just tracked down a difficult maven issue that was caused by a bad property value.

The property is a path to an alternate JVM that is used a run-time by a test.
I would like to make maven fail early by detecting if the path is valid or not.
What might be a way to accomplish this?

I plan to dig into antrun to see if there is a way to make it run first so that it can check, but that seems like overkill.

**Question**: How can I do this cleanly and simply?

Comment: To be clear: do you want to check whether the property is set or whether a file exist? It seems the title and your question ask for different things (hence the 2 different answers :D)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [`maven-enforcer-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/index.html) for this task. This plugin is used to enforce rules during the build and it has a built-in [`requireFilesExist`](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireFilesExist.html) rule:

> This rule checks that the specified list of files exist.

The following configuration will enforce that the file `${project.build.outputDirectory}/foo.txt` exists and will fail the build if it does not.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>enforce-files-exist</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>enforce</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <rules>
          <requireFilesExist>
            <files>
             <file>${project.build.outputDirectory}/foo.txt</file>
            </files>
          </requireFilesExist>
        </rules>
        <fail>true</fail>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [Enforcer Maven Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/index.html) and its [Require Property](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireProperty.html) rule, where you can enforce the existence of a certain property, optionally with a certain value (a matching regex), and fail the build otherwise.

> This rule can enforce that a declared property is set and optionally evaluate it against a regular expression.

A simple snippet would be:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>enforce-property</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <rules>
                    <requireProperty>
                        <property>basedir</property>
                        <message>You must set a basedir property!</message>
                        <regex>.*\d.*</regex>
                        <regexMessage>The basedir property must contain at least one digit.</regexMessage>
                    </requireProperty>
                </rules>
                <fail>true</fail>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Ah funny, we suggest the same plugin we not the same rule :D.

Comment: @Tunaki ahaha nice, ok then it's up to the OP to check which one suits best his/her needs.

Comment: Nice that this can compare things with a regex, but the other is a little bit simpler and will probably confuse a intern less, if we ever have one work on the code.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Require Files Exist](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireFilesExist.html) rule of the Maven Enforcer plugin.

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-files-exist</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <requireFilesExist>
                  <files>
                   <file>${property.to.check}</file>
                  </files>
                </requireFilesExist>
              </rules>
              <fail>true</fail>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```